# Weird orientation behavior android react-native

Tags: android, orientation, react-native

In a React Native app, I'm implementing a fullscreen view using a new Android activity. In the normal view, only portrait is allowed, in fullscreen, only landscape.

This is set / enforced in AndroidManifest files as follows:

Main activity:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Fullscreen activity:

```
<activity
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>
```

Now, everything works fine, only it behaves weirdly when I go back from fullscreen to normal view. I added a GIF to show it. When I go back to normal view, it rotates back to landscape once more and then goes back to portrait.

I don't see where in my React app this could go wrong, maybe someone has experience with this problem and can point me in the right direction?

[image: gif of whats happening]